# how to bind the value of a comboboxitem as checkbox text in radgrid filteritem template

Tags: telerik, grid, rad

I have a radcombobox in a flitertemplate that contains three fixed items and acts as a filter for the radgrid,also i have a checkbox in my itemtempalte to to allow users to be able to filter the grid with a combination of stauses.
       I am adding the items to the combo in my aspx page as follows:

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="rcbCallbackStatus" Width="100px" Skin="WebBlue"  
                                runat="server"  EmptyMessage="All" >
                               <Items>
                                    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="All" Value="" />
                                    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="New" Value="O" />
                                    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="In Progress" Value="I" />
                                    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="Complete" Value="C" />
                                </Items>
                              <ItemTemplate>

                                        <div>
                                             <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chk1" checked="true" onclick="onCheckBoxClick(this)" />
                                             <asp:label runat="server" id="lbl_status" text="In progress" AssociatedControlID="chk1" ></asp:label>
                                        </div>

                              </ItemTemp`enter code here`late>
                              </telerik:RadComboBox>
```

But i am not able to set the value of the comoboboxitems as a text for the checkboxes .Please can you let me know how this can be done using javascrit or vb.net in code behind.